# How to create MLOps vertex ai pipeline with custom sklearn code?

Tags: mlops, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to build MLOps pipeline using vertex ai but failing to deploy it

```
@dsl.pipeline(
    # Default pipeline root. You can override it when submitting the pipeline.
    pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
    # A name for the pipeline. Use to determine the pipeline Context.
    name="pipeline-test-1",
)
def pipeline(
serving_container_image_uri: str = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloud-aiplatform/prediction/tf2-cpu.2-3:latest"
):
    dataset_op = get_data()
    train_op = train_xgb_model(dataset_op.outputs["dataset_train"])
    train_knn = knn_model(dataset_op.outputs["dataset_train"])
    
    eval_op = eval_model(
        test_set=dataset_op.outputs["dataset_test"],
        xgb_model=train_op.outputs["model_artifact"],
        knn_model=train_knn.outputs['best_model_artifact']
    )
    
    endpoint_op = gcc_aip.ModelDeployOp(
    project=PROJECT_ID,
    model=eval_op.outputs["model_artifacts"],
    machine_type="n1-standard-4",
    )
    
    #endpoint_op.after(eval_op)
    
compiler.Compiler().compile(pipeline_func=pipeline,
        package_path='xgb_pipe.json')
```

gcc_aip.ModelDeployOp is throwing error that correct model id or name should be pass

Comment: There is not enough information to be sure, but it seems like you do not pass the correct model name. If more help is needed please share how you confirm what is available, and how you call it so people can check if there is a discrepancy.